# Regarding overfitting a model

Tags: deep-learning, model-fitting

Suppose I want to learn a dataset, and I pick a deep-NN model with some complexity (say 5-layers).

Now, I know that this model is overfitting my data when I notice that during the training, the train-loss and validation-loss both decrease until N-epochs, and then the valid-loss starts to go up after that.

My question is: Is this model good for my data if I stop at Nth epoch? Or it is an over-complicated model in the first-place, even if I stop the training at N-epochs or not. Do I just discard this architecture and hunt for a better one?

Comment: The training data you use will also impact your trained model. Using *over specified* data (with very low variance) will also cause an overfitting model.

Comment: @dboy Thanks. But assuming that  my data doesn't have any unusual amount of variance, would you know what's the answer for my question? Appreciate it.